# android's alarm manager

Tags: android

Hello I have a question about android's alarm manager, I would like to schedule an alarm that would execute using an initial interval and be able to change by the user. my code is :

```
 long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
 mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext,AlarmService_Service.class), 0);
this.setInterval(Integer.parseInt(Interval));
configShared.edit().putInt("interval", this.getInterval()).commit();
// Schedule the alarm!
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,this.getInterval(), mAlarmSender);
```

the this.getInterval() is a method to hold the interval and is used to check if user has changed the interval.

Reading the documentation I found under the parameters of alarmManagers setRepeating method that says:

triggerAtTime   Time the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type)

What exactly is this? Is the alarm canceled when I change the interval? also there's a problem cause I like this code to be executed every 5 minutes and this will execute every 5 minutes+firstinterval correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What excactly is this?

It seems fairly self-explanatory. It is the time when the alarm will first go off. Subsequent alarms will go off at your specified period after that time.

> Is the alarm canceled when I change the interval?

There is no such thing as "change the interval". You can set alarms and cancel alarms. You cannot update alarms, except by canceling the old and adding the new.

> also there's a problem cause I like this code to be executed every 5 minutes and this will execute every 5 minutes+firstinterval correct?

The first one will occur at `firstTime`. The second one will occur at `firstTime` plus five minutes. The third one will occur at `firstTime` plus ten minutes. And so on. Since `firstTime` is now, the first alarm should go off immediately.

Comment: according to the documentation "If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled." doesn't this allow you to change the interval since changing the interval cancels the old alarm and sets a new one with new interval

Comment: @maxsap: That should work, though personally I'd cancel and set the next one. There are too many layers of indirection between our code and the `IntentSender` for my taste.

Comment: as posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248181/android-alarm-manager-long-interval the code works for intervals of 5-10-20-30 minutes but when I set it to 1 hour the alarm manager acts weird and the interval gets real big numbers (3.8 hours) I will try canceling the alarm and setting a new one, maybe this is the solution to this. Thanks for the advice